# Disable click on bxslider pager

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I want to disable click event on bxslider pagers without touching core bxlslider files.  
[image]

Is it possible.. ? Please guide me in right direction.

 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you only want to use the bullets to denote the current slide. That is not the purpose of bxslider's pager bullets. I would suggest taking this approach:

1. Disable bxslider's pager bullet
2. Add a custom `ul` element with n number of `li` elements, where n is the number of slides. You can use javascript to generate the li elements dynamically.
3. Use css to make all `li` elements hollow circles as per your design requirements.
4. Now, using bxslider's `onSlideAfter` callback, add a class e.g. 'active' class to corresponding `li` element, while removing it from all sibling `li` elements. Use css to highlight this 'active' `li` item.

I can post the code, if you find this approach useful.

Answer (score 2):

In simple way, I can use CSS to disable click, using `pointer-events: none` like:

```
.bx-pager {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bxslider").bxSlider({
    maxSlides: 1,
    slideWidth: 200
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.bx-pager {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/vendor/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<ul id="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=Slide+1" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=Slide+2" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=Slide+3" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=Slide+4" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=Slide+5" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```